# google ga analytics.js linkid.js on highly generic sites

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I just wondered whether google analytics linkid is working on highly generic websites?

E.g. I have a multiple recommendation widgets on my site which are randomly generated every minute. Is google able to track this probably? What impact does it have on linkid? Is it possible to track which page area got how many clicks? E.g. Sidebar or overlay clicks?

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced link attribution works by looking at the id for the clicked element; if there isn't an event the script traverses up to look for the id of an parent element. The goes up to three nodes upwards, if it cannot find an id it silently fails.

If the ids your webpage change often due to dynamically generated widgets etc. the script will  at some technical leven still work but the collected data will be meaningless.